# How to update docker-machine on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker-machine

I installed docker-machine on my Ubuntu 18.04 with the instruction provided here: https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly. Now how do I update it to a more recent version?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate for [su] or [unix.se] , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out, it is enough to just rerun the commands for installation with changed version in the link

For example, this command installs version 0.14.0:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.14.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && \
sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

If you want to update it to 0.16.0, you just run:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && \
sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```